# Does Azure Front Door Supports Private IP backends

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-front-door

We have two Kubernetes clusters and has deployed internal NGINX ingress controllers. So they are not publicly accessible. The NGINX ingress controller has private IP assigned to it. I will be implementing Azure Front Door and I'd like to know if we can add the private IP address of the NGINX ingress controller as the backend to Front Door. Furthermore for the frontend of the Azure Front Door can we have a private IP address?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Front Door premium supports securing origins with [private link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/private-link).  I'm not certain if you can directly use a private link with your internal NGINX ingress controllers, but if you can't you can always set up an [internal load balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/standard-premium/how-to-enable-private-link-internal-load-balancer#enable-private-connectivity-to-an-internal-load-balancer) that points to the ingress controller.  The ingress controller may be the same thing, but internal load balancers support private links.

For your second question you can't have a private IP address as your front end for Front Door using only Front Door.  You could achieve this by having a resource with a private IP address (like an internal load balancer) that functions as your Front Door frontend.  You'd point its backend to your Front Door url.  Then you would create a custom WAF rule in Front Door that only allows the public IP for the resource, restricting traffic essentially to a single private IP address.

Comment: We have a full scale solution for this exact scenario here https://github.com/Azure/Mission-Critical-Connected